# GRUB records normal boot as failed and shows up

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.10

Running Ubuntu 19.10 with i3wm, I've got these lines it me /etc/default/grub which should theoretically make GRUB to wait for 5s without showing up and then booting the OS:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN=1
```

Thing is, it still shows up and has a load timeout (Time to load a default boot option) of 30s. How do I fix this behavior?

UPD:
I added

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5
```

to my config, and now load timeout is 5s, so I suppose grub just thinks that boot failed even though it was OK. Don't really know how to fix it.